# insert data if not exist in the column using Laravel elequant

Tags: eloquent, orm, laravel-7

I'm developing a doctor's appointment laravel project. the condition is if a user fixes an appointment they can't able to fix the appointment for the same doctor at the same date and time. I tried with **firstOrCreate** method but doesn't match my condition. here are my conditions

1.*if doctors_id AND date AND time already exist then shouldn't insert the data*
2.*if doctors_id OR date OR time, any three of this already exist then can insert the data*
3.*if all fields already not exist then insert data*

here are the code snippets

In view

```
    <div class="card-body">
<form action="appointment" method="post">
    {{ @csrf_field() }}
                       <select name="doctors" id="" class="form-control">

                        @foreach ($docList as $item)
                    <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select><br><br>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="" class="form-control">
                    <br><br>
                    <select name="time" class="form-control">
                        <option value="9-10AM">9-10AM</option>
                        <option value="10-11AM">10-11AM</option>
                        <option value="1-2PM">1-2PM</option>
                        <option value="2-3PM">2-3PM</option>
                        <option value="3-4PM">3-4PM</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Fix Appointment</button>
</form>
                </div>
```

In controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $uId = Auth::id();

        $fixAppointment = Appointment::firstOrNew(['doctors_id'=>$request->doctors,'date'=>request('date')],['time'=>request('time')]);
        
        $fixAppointment->users_id = $uId;

        $fixAppointment->save();
    }
```

Comment: you can also use Model::updateOrCreate(['columns']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I sorted out the issue by using **where** condition

In controller

```
 $appointment = Appointment::where('date', '=', request('date'))->where('time','=',request('time'))->where('doctors_id','=',request('doctors'))->first();

         if ($appointment === null)
         {
            $fixAppointment = New Appointment;
            $fixAppointment->doctors_id = $request->doctors;
            $fixAppointment->users_id = $uId;
            $fixAppointment->date = $request->date;
            $fixAppointment->time=$request->time;

            $fixAppointment->save();  
}
```

here is the [link](https://www.edureka.co/community/65689/how-to-check-if-a-record-already-exists-in-a-laravel) which I referred to find this solution.